# oracle how to use line feed from string

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return line feed

```
 CALC_LENGTH :=regexp_replace(CALC_LENGTH,  '([\x0B|)', ' ');
 CALC_LENGTH :=translate(CALC_LENGTH, chr(11), '     ');
```

using translate() or regexp will always give me a new line

example :

```
if PR is null then
CALC_LENGTH :=regexp_replace(CALC_LENGTH,  '([\x0B|)', ' ');
else
CALC_LENGTH := where var1 >var2;
end if;

BEGIN
select ..... from tab1
'||CALC_LENGTH||'
  insert into....
endif;
```

if pr is null I am having result with empty line even while using trasnalte or regexp.

```
select ..... from tab1

insert into....
```

I want my output result like the below:

```
select ..... from tab1
insert into....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try TRANSLATE function, it has worked for me many times in the past, with CHR. I'm not sure which ASCII will map to the desired output, you can refer to the below block and keep the desired CHR statement(s):

```
DECLARE
    CALC_LENGTH VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
    CALC_LENGTH := 'Hi!'||chr(10)||'i'||CHR(11)||'z'||CHR(12)||'y'||chr(13)||'a';
    CALC_LENGTH :=regexp_replace(CALC_LENGTH,  '[\x0B|]', ' ');
    CALC_LENGTH := TRANSLATE(CALC_LENGTH, CHR(10), ' ');
    CALC_LENGTH := TRANSLATE(CALC_LENGTH, CHR(11), ' ');
    CALC_LENGTH := TRANSLATE(CALC_LENGTH, CHR(12), ' ');
    CALC_LENGTH := TRANSLATE(CALC_LENGTH, CHR(13), ' ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('select ..... from tab1'||
                         CALC_LENGTH||
                         'insert into....');
END;
/
```

Comment: well I did try translate function but it always give me empty line

Comment: I think instead of CHR(13), if you replace all 10, 11, 12, you'll get the desired output. Since New line in ASCII is 10. Depending upon the OS and the software package you use. A new line may be represented as LF+CR or CR+LF or just CR. CR represents carriage return which is ASCII Code 13.

Comment: I added the 10 11 12 13 , i am using the calc_length  in a string like this 
Text = ' Insert ' ||CALC_LENGTH||' .... ' would this effect ?

Comment: Should not. The string will be stored as is, as long as your variable can store the length(bytes), it should be good.